# Where is my Outlook attachment downloaded?

Tags: email, downloading, outlook, attachments

I use the [Outlook app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.office.outlook) on my Android phone and I received an attachment in one of my emails. I downloaded it and it automatically opened with another app so I can read it.

Now I want to retrieve it and make a copy, on my phone. Which folder in my phone should I search to find that attached file? I searched the Download and Attachments folders, without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long press on the attachment, a window will appear with the option `Save to`. Select `Device`. The file will be downloaded in the Download folder.